# swauth vs. keystone: which is a better choice in Swift only installation?

Tags: openstack-swift, keystone

I'm trying to install Openstack Swift on CentOS 6.5. I only need object storage, so no other Openstack services will be installed. The problem I'm facing now is how to choose the auth system.

I've tried keystone, which seems a little bit too 'heavy' to me. After some Googling, I found swauth, but only a few results about it. So is it fine to use swauth as the auth system, even in a production installation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

swauth is an alternative to keystone, Its note difficult to configure and operate. It depends on how big is going to be your installation, but from my experience its pretty feasible for a mid size deployment.